# Why some delivery methods are not available for some customers?

Tags: magento-1, shipping, quote, table-rates, delivery

I have 4 shipping methods.

The old customer gets only 2 methods.
I've created the same customer with another email. It gets all 4 shipping methods.

I dived into code and DB table **sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate**.

Sorting by address_id we have:
for old customer: 2 rate records;
for the same new customer: 4 rate records.

Why does it happens? and where is rate record created?

**UPDATE 1:**

I doesn't depends on address. It depends on product. If product has filled weight then customer cannot see some shipping methods. Now the question is why?)

Comment: maybe you have restrictions on the shipping address for carrier availability. Try with a different address for the first customer that gets only 2 shipping methods. (change the state, or country or city...or all of them)

Comment: I did it - doesn't help. Anyway I have two similar customers with _only_ different email.

Comment: What shipping methods do you use?

Comment: Custom methods. Its based on freedelivery methods

Comment: Maybe 2 customers have different products with differs weight? Or some shopping cart price rules affects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason was in `proccessAdditionalValidation` function in `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` class:

```
    /**
         * Processing additional validation to check is carrier applicable.
         *
         * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
         * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract|Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Error|boolean
         */
        public function proccessAdditionalValidation(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
        {
            $maxAllowedWeight = (float) $this->getConfigData('max_package_weight');
            $error = null;
            $showMethod = $this->getConfigData('showmethod');
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct() && $item->getProduct()->getId()) {

// here I got true

                    if ($item->getProduct()->getWeight() > $maxAllowedWeight) {                         $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
                        $error->setCarrier($this->_code)
                            ->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
                        $errorMsg = $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg');
                        $error->setErrorMessage($errorMsg?$errorMsg:Mage::helper('shipping')->__('The shipping module is not available.'));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (null !== $error && $showMethod) {
                return $error;
            } elseif (null !== $error) {
                return false;
            }
            return $this;
        }
```